# Оформление цитат

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата

Вопрос по оформлению цитаты из фильма "Большой куш".

> На твоем пистолете написано: «Муляж», а на моем – «Дезерт Игл».

Чисто теоретически всякие "написано", "сказано" и так далее близки к значению речи-мысли, поэтому надо двоеточие. С другой стороны, это можно считать цитированием отдельных слов и словосочетаний, конструкции в кавычках органично встроены в предложение и выступают в роли дополнений. Допустима ли такая пунктуация или надо по-другому?

Answer (score 1):

Если пунктуация оформляется как в предложении с прямой речью, то она должна быть такой (одинаковой — что для первого названия, что для второго), с двумя двоеточиями:

***На твоем пистолете написано: «Муляж», а на моем*** [написано]**: *«Дезерт Игл».***

Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора. Примечание](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154)):

1. "Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится". (Для нас это подходит.)
2. "Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова *предложение, выражение, надпись* и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие". (Это тоже нам подходит, потому что таких слов в предложении нет.)

И еще. Муляж — это слепок или модель предмета в натуральную величину, это не марка пистолета, поэтому слово в предложении лучше написать со строчной буквы.
Я бы остановилась на таком варианте:

**На твоем пистолете написано «муляж», а на моем — «Дезерт Игл».**

*В «Спартаке» ошиблись, и на футболке было написано «Жано»* («Советский спорт»).